# Teleporting type command doesn't work with @e

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever I type `/tp @e[type=anything] @p` it teleport all entities nearby and all my named entities, even though I've specified to teleport all cows, or minecart with chests, or whatever I put under type. Is there any way to fix this or use a different command?

Edit:
 
I was using the auto fill options and I used the command that I wrote specifically i.e. `/tp @e[type=!minecraft:cow] @p`  , but it does it for anything I try. I am using vanilla `1.14.4`.

Comment: Weird. `/tp @e[type=cow] @s` works for me, in Java 1.14.4. Could you copy paste some of the commands you tried and edit them into your question? Until then, a couple things: make sure that whatever ID you use in the `type=` selector is correct, and if possible, use tab to autofill. Also, maybe use `@s` just for clarity if you are the entity running the command? Otherwise, I'm not really sure what's wrong, but we can help you better if you include the commands you've tried.

Comment: Also, what version are you in? I remember that some syntax errors caused strange results instead of an error message in 1.12 and before.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `!` which means not. You are selecting everything that is not a cow. Get rid of the `!` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried everything and it still doesn't work, you can also make every single entity **you specify** use a command to teleport to you:

```
execute as @e[type=anything] run tp @p
```

`execute as @e[type=anything]` makes it so that ALL entities that match the criteria will run `tp @p`, A.K.A. to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't we find the actual issue, instead of finding workarounds? A workaround shouldn't be needed here, so it would be better to just find the issue itself as if that isn't working some other issue is bound to come up anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Teleporting only works if you are an admin, so go to the pause menu and see if there is a crown next to your name. If it is anything else than a crown, you don't have permission to teleport. Also. cheats need to be on to teleport. Also the correct command is /tp [gamertag]. But make sure you don't use the straight parentheses. Also, instead of typing, open the chat menu and press the / on the left side of the chat bar that shows your unsent message. Then press teleport and the player's name. If the slash does not appear, cheats are disabled. So make sure you have admin permissions and cheats are activated.

Comment: There a few things wrong here. 1. Almost all the info provided is incorrect as this isn't bedrock. 2. The syntax you provided for that isn't even what they're asking, even if this was on bedrock. 3. If someone asks for command help, your advice shouldn't be to use the command help feature as when people ask for command help they want to specify their own arguments, and selectors cant even be used in that autofill thing